# How to write SQL query using a join on 3 tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, join

I have created a hypothetical scenario with some dummy data. Below are 3 basic tables and I'm looking to write a query to find what property/properties Mary has viewed. 
In this scenario Mary has viewed 1 property a flat in Glasgow.

Table 1: Client

```
=====================
ID  Name        
=====================
5   Tom
6   Mary
7   John
```

Table 2: Property

```
=====================
ID  CITY        TYPE    
=====================
14  Aberdeen    House
16  Glasgow     Flat
21  Glasgow     House
94  London      Flat
```

Table 3: Viewing

```
========================
Client  Property    Date    
========================
5       14      01-12-2016
5       21      08-12-2016
6       16      10-10-2016
```

Comment: `INNER JOIN` would be my first thought, particularly for someone learning SQL.

Comment: What are you trying to show?

Comment: SEarle1986 I was just trying to see how I would go about seeing what property Mary viewed

Comment: Sorry, missed that bit! The question has answers now but I agree with them that JOIN (Or INNER JOIN) is the way to go

Comment: Thanks SEarle1986 I see them, i'm just looking at the two answers now and trying figure them out as one uses join and the other inner Join

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely use inner joins for this, a quick example of this could be

```
SELECT c.Name, p.Type, p.City, v.Date
FROM Viewing v 
JOIN Client c ON v.client = c.ID
JOIN Property p ON v.property = p.ID
WHERE c.Name = 'Mary'
```

That should show you who view what and when. I've used aliases on the table names just to keep it neat.